# how can i Cache object and its relations in laravel 6

Tags: api, caching, laravel-6

In RatingController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\RatingResource;
use App\Models\Rating\Rating;

class RatingController extends Controller
{
    public function getRatingsByCategory($id)
    {
        $ratings = cache()->rememberForever('test', function () use ($id) {
            return new RatingResource(Rating::findOrFail($id));
        });

        return response()->json([
            'data' => $ratings
        ]);
    }
}
```

in RatingResource class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class RatingResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->rating_id,
            'is_active' => $this->is_active,
            'created_at' => '2020',
        ];
    }
}
```

when i send request to this controller, i get this result

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "created_at": "2020"
    }
}
```

but when i change each of column in RatingResource like created_at, the result changes.
indeed laravel does not cache final result, it cache the object of my request and when i return that object,it start to convert my object to resource format.
how can i cache the result of ApiResource till i delete this cache key.

Answer (score 1):

You could cache the whole response, this way you would have to add the id to the cache key though, in order to differentiate between the different rating ids.

Something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\RatingResource;
use App\Models\Rating\Rating;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class RatingController extends Controller
{
    public function getRatingsByCategory($id)
    {
        return Cache::rememberForever("test:{$id}", function () use ($id) {
            return RatingResource(Rating::findOrFail($id));
        });
    }
}
```